# Compare two IDs / Strings in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

Think this is a pretty basic query, but I just can't make it work.
Found no solution yet.

I have two tables with different data. Both tables contain a ID as a String called the clientID.

Table **A** has the ID and different events and custom dimensions from all Google Analytics Sessions.

```
SELECT 
clientId,
visitNumber,
hits.page.pagePath AS pagePath,
trafficSource.source AS source,

--Events
SUM(CASE WHEN (hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Download' AND hits.type = 
'EVENT' AND hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'pdf') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 
Downloads,
SUM(CASE WHEN (hits.eventInfo.eventLabel  = 'search-header' OR 
hits.eventInfo.eventLabel  = 'search-mainpage') AND hits.type = 'EVENT' THEN 
1 ELSE 0 END) AS Search,

--CustomDimension
(SELECT MAX(cd.value) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) AS cd WHERE 
cd.index = 1) AS realURL

FROM `xxxx.xxxx.ga_sessions_*` AS t, UNNEST(hits) AS hits

WHERE 
hits.page.pagePath LIKE 'news-and-media' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
 FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', date '2018-05-31') AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', date 
'2018-10-01')
GROUP BY 
clientId,
visitNumber,
pagePath,
source,
realURL

LIMIT 100;
```

Table **B** has only one column with some clientIDs. 
So I want to match / search for the clientIDs in Table **A** for the clientIDs that are in Table **B**.
I only want the data from Table A where the IDs matched.

I'm using Standard SQL here. Any thoghts on how to solve this?
Think I have to use a JOIN here, but not experienced with that.

Comment: You do indeed want a join - select the table with just the ID's in table B and left join Table A on `ClientID` so that only the users in table B will be present in the results. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join-types

Answer (score 0):

This should be really straightforward using IN clause (just tested, IN is supported in bigquery).

```
select * from tableA where ID in (select ID from tableB)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, a JOIN will help you achieve your objective.

Let me use the tables `tableA` and `tableB` below for an example:

```
$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT * FROM `dataset.tableA`'
+----------+------------+-----------+
| clientID | clientName | clientNum |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| id1      | aaa        |       111 |
| id1      | bbb        |       222 |
| id2      | ccc        |       333 |
| id3      | ddd        |       444 |
| id4      | eee        |       555 |
| id5      | fff        |       666 |
+----------+------------+-----------+

$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT * FROM `dataset.tableB`'
+----------+
| clientID |
+----------+
| id1      |
| id4      |
| id5      |
+----------+
```

Now you can use the JOIN operation in BigQuery in order to retrieve only the rows from **`tableA`** where the column `clientID` matches those values in the same column in **`tableB`**:

```
SELECT
  tA.clientID,
  tA.clientName,
  tA.clientNum
FROM
  `dataset.tableA` AS tA
JOIN
  `dataset.tableB` AS tB
ON
  tA.clientID = tB.clientID
```

This query provides the following results:

```
$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT tA.clientID, tA.clientName, tA.clientNum FROM `dataset.tableA` AS tA JOIN `dataset.tableB` AS tB ON tA.clientID = tB.clientID'
+----------+------------+-----------+
| clientID | clientName | clientNum |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| id1      | aaa        |       111 |
| id1      | bbb        |       222 |
| id4      | eee        |       555 |
| id5      | fff        |       666 |
+----------+------------+-----------+
```

In your case, you could either JOIN on `clientId` after retrieving from `xxxx.xxxx.ga_sessions_*`, or get the results from this query and then JOIN them on `clientId`.

Given that you are starting to work with JOINs in BigQuery, let me share with you a couple of documentation links that may be useful too:

- [Available JOIN types in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join-types)
- [Optimize JOIN patterns for BigQuery performance](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute#optimize_your_join_patterns)